How to convert Timespan as a value without days in ASP.NET Core?
I have a timespan data type, and when calculating it, if the value exceeds a day, it will have the format: d.hh:mm:ss and I expect it to have the format hh:mm:ss.
Example: 1.6:00:00 -> 30:00:00
Can I get your help with that?

What if the TimeSpan exceeds 99 hours? Should it overflow to 0? Or maybe continue going, so it will no longer be just two digits, but three or more e.g. hhh:mm:ss like a year being 8760:00:00? Have you considered these problems?

If that is not a concern, please see this answer.

I just wrote an extension method for it: http://dotnetfiddle.net/CFteyC


I have a timespan data type, and when calculating it, if the value exceeds a day, it will have the format: d.hh:mm:ss and I expect it to have the format hh:mm:ss.

The TimeSpan data structure doesn't 'have a format'. Behind the scenes, IIRC it's just an integer that measures a number of ticks, a tick being 100 ns.
When you call e.g. ToString on it, you get a string representation of the value, and this default string representation does, indeed, have the format [-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff].
As the various comments have already pointed out, you're probably best off writing a custom formatting function for your particular purpose.
On the other hand, if you just need the total number of hours, there's no reason to turn the value into a string. In that case, you can just get the value of the TotalHours property.
